# Is there a more advanced version of escapeHtml(unsafe); with a return message?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The function below is all good but it doesn't prevent such as XSS

EG: `<script>alert(test);</script>`

I would like to prevent such "attacks" as these but also return a message like:

`I tried to exploit this site, but failed!`;

Reason being is this is for a chatbox system I am building.

```js
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

Comment: It's an escaping function. It does prevent XSS just fine (can you show how you're using it where it doesn't?) by rendering any text as html content. It does just that and nothing else, it cannot distinguish between an XSS attack and content that genuinely contains special characters. (Nothing can, apart from maybe a human, as one has to figure out the intention of the sender).

Comment: @Bergi I just simply wish to prevent any XSS/Modification to my page but if they attempted it would return the Username and there message as "I tried to XSS this site" etc....

Comment: No, this is not possible. Escaping is always content-agnostic, it enables to usage of arbitrary values. What you seem to be looking for is to distinguish between valid and invalid values, e.g. forbidding user names to contain any of the `$<>"'` characters. But that's not longer "escapeHTML".

Comment: @Bergi No, thats not what I mean when I said that; I mean like:

Johnty said: `<script>alert(xss);</script>`

Now when I said that, I would like it to return instead of the text aka XSS a message like:

Johnty said: `I just tried to XSS this page.`

Comment: And there should be nothing wrong with Johnty saying that. In fact, Johnty just said that in a comment on StackOverflow, and StackOverflow does not believe that he wanted to XSS anyone with it.

Comment: @Bergi funny lol, thats due to the fact I used backticks around the code in question, but I see the humorous side of it.

Comment: "Type your name" — "O'Brian" — "I tried to exploit this site, but failed!"  // Now, seriously, and in case it isn't clear yet: there's no way a `<script>` tag can survive this function, unless you do something else later you aren't telling us (such as converting `&lt;` back to `<`). Unless you can provide a runnable snippet the illustrates the issue, I don't think there's much to answer here.